# hover behaviour should continue on overlayed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)'s `.hover()` method. I have a few paragraphs inside `a` tags which I use as a menubar. What I intend to do is, if I hover one of these menulinks, a new element gets displayed over the menulink which contains links to submenu links. The problem is, that the `.hover()` stops working immediately.

I did a simple [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1urs0wfr/) to show my problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit:** Worth to say is, that I also want the sublinks to be clicked, so the hover must be still working then. It only stops when I leave the `red` div.

Comment: To be honest didn't get what you try to achieve..

Comment: @Alek if you hover the `Hover me` paragraph the `red` displayed div should stay, but as you can see it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
$('p').hover(function() { $('div').fadeIn(); }, function() {  });
$('div').hover(function() { }, function() { $('div').fadeOut(); });
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/1urs0wfr/2/

Comment: You could even use [$.noop](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noop/) to avoid the empty functions.

Comment: thank you sir, thats it! @John any bad practice with empty functions?